# in play 2.4 logback configurations, where is ${application.home} defined?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

The link here shows you how to configure your custom logger.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsLogger

I was just wondering where is the ${applicaation.home} defined, as it seems to not have been defined in my production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated by @user316607, Play should define `application.home` by itself in the [Logger.configure method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L209). If you are seeing the value `application.home_IS_UNDEFINED` instead, and you're using [compile-time dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection), you'll need to call `Logger.configure` yourself in your `ApplicationLoader` as explained in [this blog post](http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/play24-compile-time-di/):

```
class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    new MyComponents(context).application
  }
}

class MyComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  // You have to call Logger.configure manually or logback won't work
  Logger.configure(context.environment)

  // ... The rest of your app initialization code ...
}
```

Comment: For compile-time DI in Play 2.5, Logger.configure was moved into [LoggerConfigurator](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.LoggerConfigurator), in addition to some other [changes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/0a01f5babc1022023dd6466a83d0769331ae87c8). An example of configuring the Logger is shown within lines 60-67  [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/0a01f5babc1022023dd6466a83d0769331ae87c8/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/advanced/dependencyinjection/code/CompileTimeDependencyInjection.scala).

Answer (score 4):

I feel stupid. I just realised that it's part of logback and not part of play. You can define your own variables like thus:

```
<property name="USER_HOME" value="/home/sebastien" />
```

Checkout link here for more details:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingProps

Comment: In this way, it is difficult to host the app in different servers, right?

Answer (score 1):

appliation.home is defined by play framework itself.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L199

You must have another problem.