# How ${application.home} resolved in conf/logback.xml in play framework?

Tags: logging, playframework, configuration, playframework-2.4

I am using Play Framework 2.4. This is a part of the default conf/logback.xml file Play 2.4

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2009-2016 Lightbend Inc. <https://www.lightbend.com>
  -->
<!-- The default logback configuration that Play uses if no other configuration is provided -->
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
     </encoder>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

You can see full version from [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger). My question is how exactly that ${application.home} can be resolved? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321593/5715934) answer, but didn't work.

The exact situation is when I removed `${application.home}` from `<file></file>` tag, the `logs` folder will be created outside (in Parallel with) the dist(play-restful-docker-1.0-SNAPSHOT) folder. (in production)

I can add the dist-name (play-restful-docker-1.0-SNAPSHOT) replacing ${application.home} and it creates `logs` folder inside the dist and works perfect. But it is not a good practice since it will have to be changed per every new version.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve (ex: logs are placed in x/y/z, I want them at x/k/m)?

Comment: I have trouble to get your exact question?

Comment: I am trying to add a log file (inside <appender> tag), which keeps all the logs as the application up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own conf/logback.xml and override the default one. The additional ":-." after application.home will cause it to default to the current directory if application.home is not defined.  The default logback.xml of Play 2.5 does this automatically.

```
<configuration>    
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />    
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
     </encoder>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```